# Factor $x^5+x^4-8x^3-16x^2+15x+30$ into irreducibles in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$

Tags: polynomials, factoring

Can someone please tell me how to factor $x^5+x^4-8x^3-16x^2+15x+30$ into irreducibles in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$??

Comment: The rational root theorem says all the linear roots must divide into $30$ for a start.  [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E5%2Bx%5E4-8x%5E3-16x%5E2%2B15x%2B30%3D0) doesn't find any rational roots at all.

Comment: So it is already irreducible. Problem solved.

Comment: @user202729:  In theory we could still have an irreducible quadratic factor like $x^2+1$ or $x^2-2$.

Comment: Oh yes... let me see. But generally there is no easy way to do that by hand.

Comment: @user202729 no, because a polynomial can have factors without having linear factors. For an example, just multiply together two irreducible quadratics. We still must examine whether this factors into the product of a degree 2 and degree 3 term.

Comment: In this case the $x^2+ax+b$ without root is approximately $5.370665260670595 + 4.00041182199493\times x + x^2$.